# Permutations of sets

Tags: combinatorics

In an urn there are n distinguishable white balls and n distinguishable black balls.

k white balls and k black balls are extracted . The possible permutations of the 2k balls taken from the 2n balls is equal to $\binom{2k}{k}\cdot n^k\cdot n^k$

Why is the number of permutations equal to this formula?

I tried to find the answer with an example.

In an urn there are $3$ distinguishable white balls and $3$ distinguishable black balls. Two white balls and two black balls are extracted. How many permutations of the $4$ balls can I get? I apply the formula with $k=2, n=3$ .

$ \binom{4}{2}\cdot 3^2\cdot 3^2 = 246 $

I proceed as follows to try to understand it.

I numbered each of the white balls as $1,2,3$ and the black ones $4,5,6$. If I take $2$ white balls, the possible permutations of this two white balls are $^3P_2=9$, and the same for the two black balls.

\begin{matrix}
White\, balls\, permutations &Black\,  balls\, permutations \\ 
11 &44 \\ 
12 &45 \\ 
13 &46 \\ 
21 &54 \\ 
22 &55 \\ 
23 &56 \\ 
31 &64 \\ 
32 &65 \\ 
33 &66 \\ 
\end{matrix}

Applying the rule of product I get all the combinations of the $4$ balls, (two whites and two blacks),that are equal to $9*9 =  81$.

I have here a part of the formula above $n^k\cdot n^k$, in this exemple $3^2\cdot 3^2$

Why in order to obtain the permutations is $n^k\cdot n^k$ multiplied by $\binom{2k}{k}$, in this case $\binom{4}{2}$?

I divided the problem in four different parts **(a,b,c,d)** to obtain all the 4-ball permutations in order to try to see some pattern.

**a)** Permutations after extracting  two equal white balls and two equal black balls. I made tree diagrams to obtain the 4-ball permutations.

For instance balls $11$ and $44$ are extracted. The possible permutations are:

$\begin{matrix}
{\begin{matrix}
 &  &  &  &  4  \rightarrow 1 \\ 
 &  &  &  \nearrow   &  &  & \\ 
 &  &  4  &  &  &  & \\ 
 &  &  &  \searrow  &  &  & \\ 
 &  \nearrow &  & &  1  \rightarrow  4 \\ 
 1  &  &  &   &  &  & \\
 &  \searrow  &  & & 4 \rightarrow 4 \\
 &  &  &   \nearrow &   & \\ 
 &  &  1  &  &  &  & \\ 
\end{matrix}}
&&&
{\begin{matrix}
 &  &  &  &  1  \rightarrow 4 \\ 
 &  &  &  \nearrow   &  &  & \\ 
 &  &  1  &  &  &  & \\ 
 &  &  &  \searrow  &  &  & \\ 
 &  \nearrow &  & &  4  \rightarrow  1 \\ 
 4  &  &  &   &  &  & \\
 &  \searrow  &  & & 1 \rightarrow 1 \\
 &  &  &   \nearrow &   & \\ 
 &  &  4  &  &  &  & \\ 
\end{matrix}}
\end{matrix}$

There are $6$ permutations:

$1441,1414,\textit{1144}\,\,4114,4141,4411$

In italics the 4-ball permutations included in the $81$ combinations of the rule of product above.

Applying the formula for multiset permutations$\,\,$ $^4P_{2,2}=$ $\frac{4!}{2!2!}=6$. This is equal to $\binom{4}{2}$

The two white balls $11$ can also be extracted with 
$55$ or $66$.

$\begin{matrix}
 &  &  44  &  &  &  & \\ 
 &  \nearrow &  & &  &  &  & \\ 
 11  &\rightarrow &  55  &  &   &  &  & \\
 &  \searrow  &  & & & & & \\
 &  &  66   & &   & \\ 
 &  &   & &  &  &  & \\ 
\end{matrix}$

Giving $12$ more 4-ball permutations:

$1551,1515,\textit{1155},5115,5151,5511$

$1661,1616,\textit{1166},6116,6151,6611$

Two of them included in the $81$ combinations. Up to here there are $18$ 4-ball permutation.

The white balls $22$ can be extracted with the black balls $44$, $55$
or $66$, giving $18$ more combinations; only $\textit{2244},\textit{2255},\textit{2266}$ are included in the $81$ combinations above.

The same with the balls $33$. They can be extracted with the black balls $44$, $55$ or $66$, giving $18$ more combinations; only $\textit{3344},\textit{3355},\textit{3366}$ are  included in the $81$ combinations above.

For case **a)** there are $18 + 18 + 18 = 54$  4-ball permutations. This is equal to $9$ of the $81$ combinations, $(\textit{1144},\textit{1155},\textit{1166}, \textit{2244},
\textit{2255},\textit{2266}, \textit{3344},\textit{3355},\textit{3366})$, multiplied by $\binom{4}{2}$. But this does not apply for cases **b**, **c**, **d**.

**b)** Permutations after extracting two equal white balls and two different black balls.

For instance balls $11$ and $46$ are extracted. The possible 4-ballpermutations are:

\begin{matrix}
{\begin{matrix}
 &  &  &  &  4  \rightarrow 6 \\ 
 &  &  &  \nearrow   &  &  & \\ 
 &  &  1  &  &  &  & \\ 
 &  &  &  \searrow  &  &  & \\ 
 &  \nearrow  & & &  6  \rightarrow  4 \\ 
  &  &  &  &  1  \rightarrow 6 \\ 
 &  &  &  \nearrow   &  &  & \\ 
 1  &\rightarrow &  4  &  &  &  & \\ 
 &  &  &  \searrow  &  &  & \\ 
 &   &  & &  6  \rightarrow  1 \\ 
 &  \searrow &  &  &  1  \rightarrow 4 \\ 
 &  &  &  \nearrow   &  &  & \\ 
 &  &  6  &  &  &  & \\ 
 &  &  &  \searrow  &  &  & \\ 
 &   &  & &  4  \rightarrow  1 \\ 
\end{matrix}}
 & {\begin{matrix}
 &  &  &  &  6  \rightarrow 1 \\ 
 &  &  &  \nearrow   &  &  & \\ 
 &  &  1  &  &  &  & \\ 
 &  &  &  \searrow  &  &  & \\ 
 &  \nearrow &  & &  1  \rightarrow  6 \\ 
 4  &  &  &   &  &  & \\
 &  \searrow  &  & & 1 \rightarrow 1 \\
 &  &  &   \nearrow &   & \\ 
 &  &  6  &  &  &  & \\ 
\end{matrix}}
 & {\begin{matrix}
 &  &  &  &  1  \rightarrow 4 \\ 
 &  &  &  \nearrow   &  &  & \\ 
 &  &  1  &  &  &  & \\ 
 &  &  &  \searrow  &  &  & \\ 
 &  \nearrow &  & &  4  \rightarrow  1 \\ 
 6  &  &  &   &  &  & \\
 &  \searrow  &  & & 1 \rightarrow 1 \\
 &  &  &   \nearrow &   & \\ 
 &  &  4  &  &  &  & \\ 
\end{matrix}}
\end{matrix}

The permutations from the left column of the tree diagram are 12:
$\textit{1146}, \textit{1164}, 1416, 1461, 1614, 1641, 4161, 4116, 4611, 6114, 6141, 6411$

Two permutations are included in the $81$ combinations.

Applying the formula for multiset permutations$\,\,$ $^4P_{2}=$ $\frac{4!}{2!}=12$.This is equal to $\binom{4}{2}*2!$

The two white balls $11$ can also be extracted with the black balls  $54$, $56$ 
.Giving $12*2= 24$ 4-ball permutations more. Four of them included in the $81$ combinations:

$\textit{1154}, \textit{1145},\textit{1165}, \textit{1156}$

Up to here there are $36$ 4-ball permutation.

The white balls $22$ can be extracted with the black balls $46$, $54$ or $56$
, giving $36$ more combinations; only $6$permutations $\textit{2246},\textit{2264},\textit{2254},\textit{2245},\textit{2256},\textit{2265}$ are included in the $81$ combinations above.

The same with the balls $33$. They can be extracted with the black balls $46$, $54$ or $56$
, giving $36$ more combinations; only $6$permutations $\textit{3346},\textit{3364},\textit{3354},\textit{3345},\textit{3356},\textit{3365}$ are included in the $81$ combinations above.

For case **b)** there are $36 + 36 + 36 = 108$  4-ball permutations. This is equal to $18$ of the $81$ combinations, , multiplied by $\binom{4}{2}*2!$.

**c)** Two different white balls and two equal black balls are extracted.

This case is similar to case **b**. The total number of 4-balls permutations is equal to $18$ of the $81$ combinations, multiplied by $\binom{4}{2}*2!$.

**d)** Two different white balls and two different black balls are extracted.

The possible combinations out of the $81$ are.

$\begin{matrix}
{\begin{matrix}
 &  &  45  &  &  &  & \\ 
 &  \nearrow &  & &  &  &  & \\ 
 12  &\rightarrow &  46  &  &   &  &  & \\
 &  \searrow  &  & & & & & \\
 &  &  56   & &   & \\ 
 &  &   & &  &  &  & \\ 
\end{matrix}}
 & {\begin{matrix}
 &  &  45  &  &  &  & \\ 
 &  \nearrow &  & &  &  &  & \\ 
 13  &\rightarrow &  46  &  &   &  &  & \\
 &  \searrow  &  & & & & & \\
 &  &  56   & &   & \\ 
 &  &   & &  &  &  & \\ 
\end{matrix}}
 & {\begin{matrix}
 &  &  45  &  &  &  & \\ 
 &  \nearrow &  & &  &  &  & \\ 
 23  &\rightarrow &  46  &  &   &  &  & \\
 &  \searrow  &  & & & & & \\
 &  &  56   & &   & \\ 
 &  &   & &  &  &  & \\ 
\end{matrix}}
\end{matrix}$

And for each of this combinations there are $4!$ permutations. The total number of 4-balls permutations are $9*4! = 216$, that’s equal to $9* \binom{4}{2}* 2!*2! $

And for each of this combinations there are $4!$ permutations. The total number of  permutations are $9*4! = 216$, that’s equal to $9 \binom{4}{2}* 2!*2! $

Now I add all the 4-balls permutations from **a,b,c** and **d**.

$9* \binom{4}{2} + 9*\binom{4}{2}*2! +9* \binom{4}{2}*2! + 9 \binom{4}{2}* 2!*2! $.

That’s equal to $ 9  *\binom{4}{2}* [1 + 2 + 2 + 4] = 3^2*3^2*\binom{4}{2}$.

Numerically makes sense, but I can’t understand in a more intuitively or reasonable way  why multiplying $n^k * n^k$ by $\binom{2k}{k}$ combinations you get all the 4-ball permutations.

Comment: Are these balls being taken with replacement?  Is order of selection relevant?  It sounds like $\binom{2k}{k}n^kn^k$ is the number of ways you can select $2k$ balls with replacement where $k$ of them are white and $k$ are black.  To see this, pick which $k$ of the $2k$ draws resulted in a white ball.  Then from left to right, pick which specific white ball occupied each white space in the sequence.  Repeat the process for the black balls.

Comment: If the question were phrased instead with the balls being taken without replacement and order not being relevant (*as I would have initially assumed*) then it would be $\binom{n}{k}^2$ or alternatively if the balls were taken without replacement and the order mattering it would be $\binom{2k}{k}(n\frac{k}{~})^2$ where $n\frac{k}{~}$ represents $\underbrace{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k+1)}_{k~\text{terms}}$

Comment: If the balls were taken without repaclement and the order mattering can you explain with more detail the reason why it would be $\binom{2k}{k}(n\frac{k}{~})^2$

Comment: The exact same explanation as before, just noting that in the process of choosing which ball specifically was taken at each step the number of available options decreases by one each time.

Comment: "It sounds $\binom{2k}{k}(n\frac{k}{~})^2$ is the number of ways you can select $2k$ balls with replacement where $k$ of them are white and $k$ are black" That's right.

Comment: To see this, pick which $k$ of the $2k$ draws resulted in a white ball. Then from left to right, pick which specific white ball occupied each white space in the sequence. Repeat the process for the black balls.Could you please explain it with more detail with an example. I don't quite understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of white and black, I'll use red and black in order to use color.

For my running example, I'll use $k=4$ and n=6 with $\{\color{red}{1},\color{red}{2},\color{red}{3},\color{red}{4},\color{red}{5},\color{red}{6},1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ as the set of balls.

---

> **Step 1:** Pick which $k$ of the $2k$ draws resulted in a red ball.

You will wind up with a sequence of colors such as $$\color{red}{\square}\square\color{red}{\square}\color{red}{\square}\color{red}{\square}\square\square\square$$

with exactly $k$ of them being red and $k$ of them being black.  There are $\binom{2k}{k}$ different sequences of colors.

---

> **Step 2:** From left to right, pick which specific red ball was used in each of the corresponding red spaces.

To count this, we can break it further via multiplication principle.  Step 2a: pick the first red ball.  Step 2b: pick the second red ball.  Step 2c: pick the third red ball... etc...  There are $n$ options at each step and $k$ steps total for a total of $n^k$ possible sequences of selecting the order in which the red balls appear.  (*if done without replacement, then at each step here the number of options decreases by one, leading to the falling factorial $n\frac{k}{~}$ instead of $n^k$*)

For example, the sequence $\color{red}{1},\color{red}{3},\color{red}{1},\color{red}{5}$.  In my running example then this corresponds to:

$$\color{red}{1}\square\color{red}{3}\color{red}{1}\color{red}{5}\square\square\square$$

---

> **Step 3:** Similarly to before, we now from left to right pick which specific black ball was used in each of the remaining spaces.

With the same explanation as in step 2, we wind up with again $n^k$ different sequences of $k$ black balls.

For example, the sequence $1,2,2,2$.  In my running example then this corresponds to the sequence

$$\color{red}{1}1\color{red}{315}222$$

---

Since the number of options at each step doesn't depend on the previous specific choice selected at the previous steps, and that every overall outcome is counted by exactly one sequence of choices, by [multiplication principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) the total number of outcomes is the product of the number of options available at each step.

I.e. there are $\binom{2k}{k}\cdot n^k\cdot n^k$ ways in which you can select $2k$ balls with replacement out of $n$ red and $n$ black balls and have exactly $k$ of the balls be red and $k$ be black.

Comment: I understood it. Thank you very much!